# ACL implementation based on variable and not static roles

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-acl

I would like to use Zend's ACL (`Zend\Permissions\Acl`) not (only) based on static roles but also on (variable) user points.

In my application every user has points. A resource has a minimum of points needed to view it. Access to a resource should be based on the number of points the user currently has.

**Example**

Resources:

- Resource 1: 20 points
- Resource 2: 100 points
- Resource 3: 150 points

Users:

- User 1: 70 points => Access to resource 1
- User 2: 135 points => Access to resources 1, 2
- User 3: 170 points => Access to resources 1, 2, 3

What would be the best way to do this?

**My thoughts so far**

1. Create ACL object dynamically for the currently logged in user based on his points (set each `$acl->allow()` based on points). This isn't clean.
2. Create a generic ACL and somehow pass the user's points (I managed to do it with assertions. See my answer below.)
3. Some (possibly easier/cleaner) way suggested here...

I would greatly appreciate a push in the right direction :)

Comment: It's common to dynamically build the ACL from defs stored in a database. It would be simple to take into account the points to do this too. You could use Assertions to check thresholds of points no problem

Comment: Could someone please take a look at my attempt to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is not just about Zend but working with ACLs in general.

Usually when you implement access rights in an ACL you assign it to a group rather than an individual user. Then you can easily (and dynamically) add or remove users from groups.

In Zend ACL you can think of these groups as the roles. In your case you assign the access rights for a resource to a group (or role) that represent a certain number of points. Now you only have to worry about moving users between these groups based on the points they have earned.

Comment: This is what worries me. The number of different points/scores is really high and i would therefore have a lot of setup work to do which doesn't seem right for such an easy task (compare current points to needed points). That's why I'm asking for a more elegant solution. To make it clear: I have read (and hopefully understood) the complete documentation on this but am still unsure of how to do it.

Comment: @lorey That's a common misconception that an easy task is quick to implement. In fact it is easy to implement but where it usually gets tricky is like with your project and that number of different points/scores.

Comment: There has to be an easier way than this. If I'm getting you right, you're suggesting to have groups like `0to25points`, `26to29points`, `30to69points` up to 5000? Imho it would at least be easier to create one specific ACL object for the current user. Correct me, if I got it wrong...

Comment: @lorey ACL objects are usually tied to resources, not users. If you had it linked to a user you would need to add a ACL to a resource for each an every (new) user. It's a little difficult to see the whole picture of your project and come up with a best solution.

Comment: I know I would be "bending" the ACL concept if I do it like this. That's why I'm hoping there is a better solution. I understand that it's difficult. I hope tough, that somebody has done something similar and already has a clean solution :)

Comment: I will add a simple example today, you're over complicating it ;)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your effort :)

Comment: I also posted the solution I came up with for now. It would be really nice if you would also take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I tried to implement it myself. Maybe it's not pretty, but it's the best solution I came up with myself. Is this the right direction? I would appreciate any feedback!

**Solution:**

Instead of strings as resources and roles i use my models ([suggested here](http://www.aviblock.com/blog/2009/03/19/acl-in-zend-framework/)). I use `PointResourceInterface` to mark resources that require a specific number of points and implement `Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\RoleInterface` in my user class. Now I create a new `NeededPointsAssertion`:

```
class NeededPointsAssertion implements AssertionInterface
{
    public function assert(Acl $acl, RoleInterface $role = null, 
            ResourceInterface $resource = null, $privilege = null) {
        // Resource must have points, otherwise not applicable
        if (!($resource instanceof PointResourceInterface)) {
            throw new Exception('Resource is not an PointResourceInterface. NeededPointsAssertion is not applicable.');
        }

        //check if points are high enough, in my app only users have points
        $hasEnoughPoints = false;
        if ($role instanceof User) {
            // role is User and resource is PointResourceInterface
            $hasEnoughPoints = ($role->getPoints() >= $resource->getPoints());
        }

        return $hasEnoughPoints;
    }
}
```

`PointResourceInterface` looks like this:

```
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\ResourceInterface;

interface PointResourceInterface extends ResourceInterface {
    public function getPoints();
}
```

**Setup:**

```
$acl->allow('user', $pointResource, null, new NeededPointsAssertion());
```

Users have access to resources that need points. But additionally the `NeededPointsAssertion` is checked.

**Access:**
I'm checking whether access is allowed like this:

```
$acl->isAllowed($role, $someResource);
```

If there's a user `$role = $user` otherwise it's `guest` or something else.

Inspiration is from http://www.aviblock.com/blog/2009/03/19/acl-in-zend-framework/

Update: Looking back at it now, it would have also been possible to add the needed points via the constructor and store it as an attribute. Decide for yourself and what makes sense in your application...